# Attaching mouse events to a Raphael rect

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to draw rectangles with the mouse using the Raphael 2+ library (note: the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661103/raphael-drawing-shapes-with-mouse) won't work with Raphael 2).

With rectangles ([Paper.rect](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.rect)), the mousedown/mouseup events only trigger when the cursor is on the edge of the rectangle and not within it. Is there a way to attach these events so they trigger when the mouse cursor is within the rectangle?

Ultimately, I'm trying to draw marquees/frames with the mouse. Ideally, I'd like to attach mouse listeners to the paper, but this is no longer possible, so I'm creating a 'surface' rect on the paper and drawing my elements within it. Is this approach whack? Any ideas most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've played around, and it seems that you have to *fill* your shape in order to have your events fired. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/bathz/KrpKs/

That just makes sens to me, It enables you to sharply define the perimeter of what you listen to. I guess you could fill the shape with a transparent color, but I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't suppose you know how to propagate events through elements? When tracking mouse movements from an object under another object, the events stop when the mouse passes over the topmost element (they're not passed through to the bottom element).

Comment: Hem, unfortunately, I haven't any experience in event handling using raphael. Maybe this answer can put you on the way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617548/why-is-dragging-in-raphael-broken-by-stopping-propagation-of-mousemove-in-an-enc . Maybe also this Raphael example can help you (however it implements mouse drag) : http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html .

Comment: Thanks again. With more playing around, I've bypassed the Raphael event mechanism altogether and attached handlers to the svg element itself. Much nicer.